# How to use LOAD DATA INFILE correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have so many data records and I want to import it into a table in database. I'm using phpmyadmin. I typed

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/cobacobaa.csv' INTO TABLE akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`

but the result came like this:
[image]

I do not know why it said that I have duplicate entry "0" for primary, but actually in my data there is no duplicate entry, here is a part of my data
[image]

could you please help me to solve this? what may I do to solve that problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that your primary key is a number.  The problem would then be that the value starts with a double quote.  When converting a string to a number, MySQL converts the leading numeric characters -- with no such characters, the value is zero.

The following might fix your problem:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/cobacobaa.csv'
    INTO TABLE akdhis_kelanjutanstudi
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

I usually load data into a staging table, where all the values are strings, and then convert the staging table into the final version.  This may use a bit more space in the database but I find that the debugging process goes much faster when something goes wrong.